# Как в java создать массив?

Tags: java

Как в java создать массив, чтобы он был сразу заполнен? Без `for`.

Можно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При создании экземпляра массива можно задать ему значения в фигурных скобках через запятую

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[]{new Object(), new Object(), new Object()};
//или Object[] objArray = {new Object(), new Object(), new Object()};
String[] stringArray = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
//или String[] stringArray = {"1","2","3"};
int[] intArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
//или int[] intArray = {1,2,3};
```

Чтобы заполнить массив начальными идентичными данными, можно воспользоваться `Arrays.fill()` [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181518/3212712):

```
int [] myarray = new int[num_elts];
Arrays.fill(myarray, 42);
```

или так:

```
Integer[] arr = Collections.nCopies(3, 42).toArray(new Integer[0]); //[42, 42, 42]
```

но этот способ также использует цикл.

Comment: это я знаю. А можно чтобы у всех было одиннаковое?

Допустим хочу создать массив boolean все из true

Comment: @ТупойХакер, обновил ответ

Comment: @zRrr, добавил это в ответ)

Comment: А можно ли с помощью Arryas заполнить пустой массив из разных значений?
Чтобы не одинаковыми

Comment: @ТупойХакер, тут только если вручную, как в начале ответа написано. Или вы как-то это себе иначе предсталяете? Как можно ещё более упростить простое перечисление значений для ячеек массива?

Answer (score 6):

```
Arrays.fill(array, -1);
```

П. С. Найдено в гугле за 17 секунд по запроссу [java init array with one value](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20init%20array%20with%20one%20value)